# Daylocator matplotlib shows day multiple times per day

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot datetimes in such a way that you see the date, say the hour of the day on one line of the x axis, and then the day and month, for example 07-26 on the second line of the x axis.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator())  
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.HourLocator([00,4,8,12,16,20]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H'))
ax.tick_params(pad=15)
ax.plot(dictionary_sorted[first_information].iloc[0:200,0],dictionary_sorted[first_information].iloc[0:200,1],'b-')
ax.set_ylabel(first_information, color='b')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.set_ylabel(second_information, color='r')
ax1.plot(dictionary_sorted[second_information].iloc[0:200,0],dictionary_sorted[second_information].iloc[0:200,1],'r-')
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: plot outcome]

As there are only two or three days shown in the plot, I would want the second line to be much less crowded, showing each date only once. So that it shows 07-26 once, and then 07-27, etc.

**EDIT**

As remarked below: If I put the code setting the locators below the plot command it works perfectly!

Comment: how about plotting names vertical like this? plt.ax(x, labels, rotation='vertical')

Comment: First put the setting of the locators and formatters *after* the `plot` command. If that doesn't help, update the question with the new code and output.

Comment: Thank you very much ImportanceOfBeingErnest! That solved it!